# Which is the best way to remove middle element of associative array in PHP?

Tags: php

Please tell me which is the best way to unset middle element of associative array in PHP?

Suppose I have an array of 10,000 elements and I want to remove middle element of that array, which is efficient way to remove middle element?

```
$temp = array('name1'=>'value1','name2'=>'value2',...,'name10000'=>'value10000');
$middleElem = ceil(count($temp) / 2);
$i = 0; 
foreach ($temp as $key=>$val) {
if ($i == $middleElem) {
 unset($temp[$key]);
 break; 
}
$i++;
}
```

Is above code efficient way?

Comment: An even-numbered array does not have a 'middle element'. Consider an array with 4 elements. There's element 1, 2, 3 and 4; which one's the middle element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$temp = Array("name1"=>"value1","name2"=>"value2",...,"name10000"=>"value10000");
$middleElem = ceil(count($temp)/2);
$keys = array_keys($temp);
$middleKey = $keys[$middleElem];
unset($temp[$middleKey]);
```

There ^_^

Comment: Uhhhhmmm no? Not correct... Take for example an array with three items. Which item wel be unset you think?

Comment: I was adapting the OP's code to get it to do what they wanted. I didn't spend time working out all the bugs and glitches, that's their job. (sorry if that came out rude...)

Comment: @Kolink WTF. "I was adapting the OP's code to get it to do what they wanted.". It clearly doesn't do what OP wants if it has bugs...

Comment: In a nutshell: unset($arr[array_keys($arr)[ceil(count($arr)/2)]]); But keep in mind that this syntax is only allowed from php 5.4.x

Answer (score 6):

Considering `$array` is your array, this code remove the middle element if it has odd number of elements. If its event it'll remove the *first of 2 middle elements*.

```
$i = round(count($array)/2) - 1;
$keys = array_keys($array);
unset ($array[$keys[$i]]);
```

**Test Result:** http://ideone.com/wFEM2

The thing you have to figure out is what you want to do when you have an array with an even number of elements. What element do you want to get then?

The above code picks the 'lower' element, the code could easily be edited to make it pick the 'higher' element. The only thing you have to check is (what all others answers failed to do) what happens if you have three elements. It doesn;t pick the middle element, but the last. So you would have to add a check for that then.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a proper way to do it. Try this:

```
array_remove_at( $temp, ceil(count($temp) / 2) - 1);
function array_remove_at(&$array, $index){
    if (array_key_exists($index, $array)) {
        array_splice($array, $index, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find the size of the array, divide that number by two and then proceed to remove the element. Not sure about the performance isssues about that though

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I wouldn't worry too much about what is the most efficient way at this point. You're much better off coding for how easy the code is to read, debug and change. Micro-optimisations like this rarely produce great results (as they're often not the biggest bottlenecks).

Having said that, if you want a solution that is easy to read, then how about using [array_splice](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php).

```
$temp = array('name1'=>'value1','name2'=>'value2',...,'name10000'=>'value10000');
$middleElem = ceil(count($temp) / 2);
array_splice( $temp, $middleElem, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take it that the following code is more efficient, because you don't have to execute it in a loop. I generally follow the same pattern as Kolink, but my version checks if there actually *is* a "middle element". Works on all types of arrays, I think.

```
<?php

for( $i = 0; $i <= 9; $i ++ ) {
    $temp['name'.$i] = 'value'.$i;
}

if( ( $count = count( $temp ) ) % 2 === 0 ) {
    /** Only on uneven arrays. */
    array_splice( $temp, ( ceil( $count ) / 2 ), 1 );
}

var_dump( $temp );
```

**EDIT**: Thavarith seems to be right; array_splice is *much* faster than simply unsetting the value. Plus, you get the added benefit of not having to use array_keys, as you already now at what `$offset` the middle is.

Answer (score 0):

Proper way seems to be:

```
unset(arr[id]);
arr = array_values(arr);
```

For first removing element at index `id` and then re-indexing the array `arr` properly.

Answer (score -1):

unset($myArray[key])
since your array is associative, you can drop any element easily this way